# Week reputation greater than overall reputation

Tags: discussion, bug

How is this possible? Week reputations are greater than user's overall reputation. Even though If we consider the fact that user might have got negative points, then that would apply to both week and overall reputations. Or is it that only positive score is considered in week reputations. No! I don't think so.

[Link to the user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8299776/praveen-thirumurugan)

[image]

Comment: Bounties given away?

Comment: Why didn't you actually link to the user?

Comment: @Servy Added a link to the user as anyone can just look at the week reputation list to find it out anyway.

Comment: @Servy I did not wanted to disclose the user ultimately.

Comment: Maybe the [voting corrected](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8299776/praveen-thirumurugan?tab=reputation) got something to do with that ...I blame caching ...

Comment: I think this is a bug. As I saw the profile of that user, total reputation is 156 only. and has joined 2 community. that's it. the total of that cann't be 370.

Comment: 20 hours ago he has earn 200+ reputations. And he has joined SO 5 days ago. I think this is his second profile. Moderator should investigate on that.

Comment: @CodeLღver Yes. And the activity bar shows 301 reputations for 16th July 2017. Exceeding the daily maximum.

Comment: @AmitChigadani The 200 rep cap is from rep from upvotes, not rep from all sources.  The user got 100 rep from the association bonus, which isn't rep from  upvotes.

Comment: @AmitChigadani I don't how it is possible. I am here from last 5 years and more but 1 or 2 times got this opportunity.

Comment: @AmitChigadani I saw the reputation where -147 has been deducted due to " Voting corrected" means voting from the same user. Its happens some times. when use was doing some wrong. So now I think everything will be clear that his -147 reputation has been revers

Comment: Saw that. I think we have deviated from the actual question here. My original question was why week reputations are greater than total reputations regardless of the voting reversal.

Comment: This already has been asked a few days ago. The week reputation includes points from deleted posts. Cross-site dupe: [What does this reputation mean?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/164602)